# How should I handle query synchronization in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization

I would like to insert some value into a table, which has an auto-incrementing field as a primary key. Then I want to retrieve the ID by using `mysql_insert_id()` and use this ID as a foreign key in another table. The problem is - although very unlikely - it may happen that between the first insertion and the later retrieving, another insertion happens into the first table, thus a wrong ID will be given back.

Does PHP handle this automatically, or are my concerns valid? If so, how can I overcome them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysql_insert_id() will return the last inserted id on a per connection base. So basically, you don't have to worry about concurrent script requests, if that is your worry.

For reference: [see the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).

**Edit:**

BTW, you could test this quite easily.

test.php

```
<?php

    $sleep = isset( $_GET[ 'sleep' ] ) ? true : false;

    $conn = mysql_connect( /* your parameters */ );
    mysql_select_db( /* your db */, $conn );

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO yourtable(id,col1,col2) VALUES(null,"test","test")';
    mysql_query( $sql );

    if( $sleep ) sleep( 5 );

    echo mysql_insert_id();
?>
```

open two browser tabs:

request this in the first:
http://localhost/test.php?sleep=1

request this in the second within, say, 4 seconds max:
http://localhost/test.php

First request should give you an ID less than the second request.

Comment: +1 - I'm pretty sure the php function just does a query for last_insert_id(), which says "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client"

Comment: @ryeguy: I believe so too. I even believe PHP's mysql_insert_id() is a proxy to the C API's mysql_insert_id(). (Not entirely sure, but I think I've seen this mentioned about other PHP functions, so it wouldn't surprise me). And the C API function, is mentioned in the MySQL docs I referred to.

Answer (score 3):

[SQL transactions](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm) are what you need. In MySQL, InnoDB is the only engine that supports transactions.

Comment: Not sure why this was downmodded (well, it is a PHP question...), but basically -- if you ever have one query that depends on the result of another query, you need to use a transaction.  Anything else is a hack.  (The last insert id is a special case with MySQL, however.)

Comment: Not using transactions may not be ACID but that doesn't mean it is a hack. There are many data relations that can be manipulated safely without need for transactions. Knowing which do and which don't is a different issue. But don't assume that all database applications MUST have transactions.

Answer (score -2):

There are two general strategies that you can use to ensure that this problem does not impact you. First, you can use transactions (as another author pointed out).

However from a performance perspective, it may be faster for you to manually track Id numbers. You can do this by using a global id in the database. A rolling number that makes ids in the system globally unique.

Lets say the global id is 100 and you know that you are going to need 6 ids. Then you write out 106 to the global id row in the global id table... then you use 101 for the first entry, which is the foreign key in the 102 data point and so on. This improves performance considerably when working on large data sets.

So if you need to make 100 new inserts this might be a good idea. If you only need 6 at a time.. use transactions...

As suggested by jmucchiello in comments. You can use an Update statement to ensure that another process is not writing to the global id entry. Something like

update globaltable set id = 106 where id = 100

I can see that I am getting modded down on this answer, but this really is the best strategy if you have a million rows to import... oh well...

-FT

Comment: But if two concurrent queries retrieve the same global ID from the database (which may happen, because reading, deciding and overriding is not an atomic operation) they will start using the same IDs, which cannot be allowed when you need unique keys.

Comment: kahoon: update globaltable set id = 106 where id = 100. Assuming that is the whole transaction (or you are using a mysql database that does not support transactions) you have atomicity.

Comment: kahoon: as jmuchhiello points out, if some other process is updating the global id, then the id will not be 100... and nothing will change. Of course you do need to check to see what the results of your query were. Surprising that I am getting voted down on this, since my approach is workable if inconvenient, and I am not pretending it is anything other than inconvenient. Oh well.